# Bind makeprg to a shell command

Tags: key-bindings, makeprg

I want to make something like this:

```
let &makerpg = '[ -f Makefile] && make || cd build && [ -f Makefile ] && make || cd ../build && [ -f Makefile ] && make || echo "Error"'
```

My goal is to make `make` to work in any place if it is within this kind of tree:

```
/Proyect-root
 /src
 /build
 /include
```

Edit: Actually I already have a pretty similar map:

```
nnoremap <silent><F4> :wa<bar>cd ../build<bar>make<cr><cr>:cd -<cr>:echo 'Done'<cr>
```

It's quite simple but obviously it doesn't work if I am in the root of my project.

Comment: In my plugins, I've taken another approach: I auto-detect, or register, where the actual build directory is (I can change it to switch between compilation modes), and always set `makeprg` to `cd {thebuilddir} && make $*`

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do sh/bash commands, you should run it via `sh -c`

```
let &makeprg = 'sh -c "..."'
```